# AngularJS - how to change the value of ngModel in custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-model

Lets take a look to my directive:

```
angular.module('main').directive('datepicker', [
function() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$modelValue = 'abc'; // this does not work
            // how do I change the value of the model?
```

So, how do I change the value of the ng-model?

Comment: Why don't you change the `$scope` value related? For now I've only used `$modelValue` to read it. Btw, the fourth attribute of the link function is `ngModelController` in your case, you should call it `controller` ;)

Comment: @glepretre, how can I use scope? model is passing via html like this `<input ng-model="anythingModel">` and I dont know the name of the model to use it with scope. and about `controller` call. Take a look at [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)this, how do they call it. But its wrong too, I think the best name probably will be `ngModelCtrl`

Comment: I tried all solutions from here but neither is supposed to work :(

Answer (score 57):

There are different ways of doing it:

1. `$setViewValue()` updates the view and the model. Most cases it is enough.
2. If you want to disconnect view from the model (e.g. model is a number but view is a string with thousands separators) then you could access directly to `$viewValue` and `$modelValue`
3. If you also want to overwrite the content of `ng-model` (e.g. the directive changes the number of decimals, updating also the model), inject `ngModel: '='` on the scope and set `scope.ngModel`

e.g.

```
  return {
     restrict: 'A',
     require: 'ngModel',
     scope: {
         ngModel: '='
     },
     link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

        function updateView(value) {
            ngModelCtrl.$viewValue = value;
            ngModelCtrl.$render(); 
        }

        function updateModel(value) {
            ngModelCtrl.$modelValue = value;
            scope.ngModel = value; // overwrites ngModel value
        }
 ...
```

**LINKS:**

- 1st option is discussed [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8131)
- [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) official docs

Comment: Ahhh! Finally. Thanks "brah"! I missed the `scope ngModel: '='`

Answer (score 31):

To work with complex binding expressions you should use the [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24parse) service and the `assign` method.

For more information watch this video from ng-conf - it's all about the cool things you can do with the ng-model directive: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVzymluqmg4

```
app.directive('datepicker', ['$parse',
    function($parse) {
        return {
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
                // $parse works out how to get the value.
                // This returns a function that returns the result of your ng-model expression.
                var modelGetter = $parse(attributes['ngModel']);
                console.log(modelGetter(scope));

                // This returns a function that lets us set the value of the ng-model binding expression:
                var modelSetter = modelGetter.assign;

                // This is how you can use it to set the value 'bar' on the given scope.
                modelSetter(scope, 'bar');

                console.log(modelGetter(scope));
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

What you tried is actually working: [see this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QrSIdj3iADO0LMr8yHXh?p=preview)

You don't "see" it in the input because changing the model this way doesn't call `controller.$render()` to set the new  `controller.$viewValue`.

But why don't you simply change the `$scope` value (unless you don't know it, but it would be weird):

```
angular.module('main').directive('datepicker', [function() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
          var model = attributes['ngModel'];
          scope[model] = 'bar';
        }
    };
}]);
```

And in your html:

```
<input ng-model="yourVariable" datepicker>
```

**EDIT:** (dynamic solution)

```
angular.module('main').directive('datepicker', [function() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
          // get the value of the `ng-model` attribute
          var model = attributes['ngModel'];

          // update the scope if model is defined
          if (model) {
            scope[model] = 'bar';
          }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: but what if I change `<input ng-model="yourVariable" datepicker>` to `<input ng-model="myVariable" datepicker>`. How directive will react? Note, that I need reusable directive

Comment: Your directive is reusable but `ng-model="foo"` must match `$scope.foo` to work, that's the point. I edited my answer to provide another solution to make it more dynamic.

Comment: its still not reusable enough. What if I use complex models as `users[0].educations[1].name` ?

Comment: It will not work if your ngModel is bound to smth like "objectOnScope.nestedValue"

Comment: @AlexLapa Yes I know, it was not required in the question. That's why I did not used `$parse` in my answer but I'm a fair-player, I upvoted Sly_cardinal's one :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for a `DatePicker` on my site

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
         scope.$apply(function(){
             ngModel.$viewValue = value;
         }
}
```

Comment: I tried this one but still do not update model on page.

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: I was desperate and this is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122371/angularjs-custom-directive-for-datepicker-do-not-update-ng-model

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best explanation I've encountered. This helped me big time, and brings together details from a number of the other answers here.

TIP: Be careful to read the whole article rather than skim it, or else you are likely to miss some key bits!

https://www.nadeau.tv/post/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/